# JUnit Test Constructor Injection of List of Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to write tests for the following class, where map fields are being injected through constructor injection with an argument list of dependencies. How can I mock the dependencies?

```java
@Component
public class ComponentInputValidator {
    private final Map<String, FaceInterface> faceMap;
    private final Map<String, ArmsInterface> armsMap;
    private final Map<String, MobilityInterface> mobilityMap;
    private final Map<String, MaterialInterface> materialMap;
    private final RobotComponentStock robotComponentStock;

    public ComponentInputValidator(List<MaterialInterface> materialList, 
                                   List<FaceInterface> faceList, 
                                   List<ArmsInterface> armsList,
                                   List<MobilityInterface> mobilityList,  
                                   RobotComponentStock robotComponentStock){
        this.faceMap = faceList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(faceInterface -> faceInterface.getCode().name(), Function.identity()));
        this.armsMap = armsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(armsInterface -> armsInterface.getCode().name(), Function.identity()));
        this.mobilityMap = mobilityList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(mobilityInterface -> mobilityInterface.getCode().name(), Function.identity()));
        this.materialMap = materialList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(materialInterface -> materialInterface.getCode().name(), Function.identity()));
        this.robotComponentStock = robotComponentStock;
    }

    public boolean validateStockAvailability(RobotComponent robotComponent){
        String face = robotComponent.getFace();
        String arms = robotComponent.getArms();
        String mobility = robotComponent.getMobility();
        String material = robotComponent.getMaterial();

        Code faceCode = faceMap.get(face).getCode();
        Code armsCode = armsMap.get(arms).getCode();
        Code mobilityCode = mobilityMap.get(mobility).getCode();
        Code materialCode = materialMap.get(material).getCode();


        if (robotComponentStock.getQuantity(faceCode)<1 ...{
            ...
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

FaceInterface, ArmsInterface, MobilityInterface, MaterialInterface are interfaces that have different implementations.

What I tried:

```java
    @MockBean
    private RobotComponentStock robotComponentStock;
    @MockBean
    private List<FaceInterface> faceInterfaceList;
    @MockBean
    private List<MobilityInterface> mobilityInterfaceList;
    @MockBean
    private List<ArmsInterface> armsInterfaceList;
    @MockBean
    private List<MaterialInterface> materialInterfaceList;
    @InjectMocks
    private ComponentInputValidator componentInputValidator;
```

Got an error:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException:
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'componentInputValidator' of type 'class com.demo.robot_factory.service.ComponentInputValidator'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null
for the line

```java
faceList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(faceInterface -> faceInterface.getCode().name(), Function.identity()));
```

Comment: what do you mean "how"? You tagged your question with Mockito, so its that obvious?

Comment: i don't think we need to test bean ComponentInputValidator, it's better if we treat it like normal class and write unit test with it. Then we can pass different parameters to see if the constructor work as expected.

Comment: I can't figure out how to write mock? Could you please show me how to do it? I tried several ways but received null pointer exception. I know I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure it out. I'm stuck with this.

Comment: Can you post some of the ways you tried? and where exactly you are getting a NPE?

Comment: @ParthManaktala What I want to do is sth like this:
given(robotComponentStock.getQuantity(faceCode)).willReturn(0);
assertThat(componentInputValidator.validateStockAvailability(robotComponent)).isFalse(); How can I write MockBean and InjectMocks ?

Comment: @ParthManaktala When I try to do 
(at)Mock
private RobotComponentStock robotComponentStock
(at)InjectMocks
private ComponentInputValidator componentInputValidator
Getting an error:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
Cannot instantiate InjectMocks field named 'componentInputValidator' of type 'class com.paro.robot_factory.service.ComponentInputValidator'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null

Comment: @ParthManaktala NullPointerException is caused by this line:
this.faceMap = faceList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(faceInterface -> faceInterface.getCode().name(), Function.identity()));
So, I have to mock other parameters of construction injection (list of interfaces) and they have to be put in the maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing **two different concepts** in your test.
`@MockBean` is a Spring annotation used in *Integration Tests*. It will create a mock and Spring's normal injection mechanism will inject it into your Bean.
`@InjectMock` on the other hand is an annotation from Mockito used in *Unit Tests*.

I can recommend this Blog Post on the Subject:
[@Mock vs. @MockBean When Testing Spring Boot Applications](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/)

If you want to write a Unit Test I would suggest swapping all the `@MockBean` annotations with Mockitos `@Mock`.

```
// same for the other dependencies you want to mock
@Mock
private List<MaterialInterface> materialInterfaceList;

@InjectMocks
private ComponentInputValidator componentInputValidator;
```

This should fix the exception.

---

Looking at your code I would suggest a totally different approach for your test.
I don't understand why you want to mock the Lists in the first place. Can't you just instantiate the Lists and construct your `ComponentInputValidator` by hand? For example:

```
@Test
void test(){
  List<MaterialInterface> materialList = List.of(...)
  //initialize your other dependencies here

  //pass all Lists into the constructor
  var validator = new ComponentInputValidator(materialList,...)

  //make your assertions on the validator
}
```

Comment: 1) I did as you suggested, changed MockBean to Mock (it was wrong, my bad) but this time got an exception at line Code faceCode = faceMap.get(face).getCode(); as maps were not "populated". 2) I did as you said, instantiated everything except map population. Mocked only robotComponentStock, as I want given(robotComponentStock.getQuantity(faceCode)).willReturn(0); and it worked. Thanks a lot. But I would like to solve it as well as your first proposal as I spend a lot of time to find out how to do it.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer I really think you were going down the wrong track there. Mocks are a great tool for changing the behavior of a component, as you did with your `RobotComponentStock`. I would claim that is not what you want to do with all the Lists. They are just variables used to transport data. What you are trying to do is basically the same as mocking a `String` and passing the mock into a function although you only want to pass data – makes no sense, IMHO.